# The ShippingStateCode field contains 21, which is not an available state

Tags: integration, picklist, country-and-state

I changed some integration values from the country / state pick list:
[image: State and Country Configuration]

When I try to insert a record by integration, I get the error: **"The ShippingStateCode field contains 21, which is not an available state. Your administrator can add it for you"**.

I created a record by UI and after save, I checked the field where StateCode is different from State. Is this the expected behavior?
[image: Record created on UI]

I review the [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222178/state-country-picklist-the-billingstatecode-field-contains-new-jersey-which-is) but it wasn't helpful for me. If I understand correctly, when I change the integration value, I can use the new value to integrate the records, right? So, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration Value is different from the State Code.

State Name and Integration Value both are the same and both refer to the State field.

1. **State Name**: The value in the Name field displays to users who interact with your picklist.
2. **Integration Value**: The value in the integration field is used in Apex, SOQL, etc.

Please refer to this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_integ_values.htm&type=5

"**The ShippingStateCode field contains 21, which is not an available state. Your administrator can add it for you**" to resolve this error you need to create a new State with Sate Code as '21'. Since Salesforce does not allow to edit state codes for existing ones.

Comment: About the [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_integ_values.htm&type=5) **The integration value is used by: [...] API queries and integrations [..]** does not refer to creating / changing a record via API using the integration value? Thanks!

Comment: Integration Value is also used via API to populate the state field.

Answer (score 1):

Integration Values are meant to solve this problem:

"I want to enable state and country picklists in an existing org, but I have an API integration that updates data using the full names of states and countries in the text-type `State` and `Country` fields, and I don't have time to update the integration to use the `StateCode` and `CountryCode` fields instead. I need a way to tell Salesforce that when I use 'California' in the `State` field, I really want it to put "CA" in the `StateCode` field."

So Integration Values are only meant to be used in the text-type `State` and `Country` fields, whereas the code values are meant to be used in the picklist-type `StateCode` and `CountryCode` fields. It's a way to associate a long-form name with the picklist value, even when it doesn't match the code.

So in your example, you can either put '21' in the `ShippingState` field, or put 'PB' in the `ShippingStateCode` field, but not vice versa.